# How to pass parameter from query to subquery ? ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I get ORA-00904 invalid identifier error, from this query

```
SELECT 
    tab1."col1" AS ID, 
    tab1."col4" AS Name,
    tab1."col5" AS Place,
    (SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (one_row , ';'), 2) myConString
          FROM (SELECT tab2."col3" || ',' || tab2."col4" AS one_row, 
                       ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY tab2."col1") rn, 
                       COUNT (*) OVER () cnt 
                FROM dbo."table2" tab2 
                WHERE tab2."col1" = tab1."col1" 
                AND tab2."col2" = tab1."col2") 
    WHERE rn = cnt 
    START WITH rn = 1
    CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1) 
FROM dbo."table1" tab1  
WHERE tab1."col1" IN (1,2,3) 
AND tab1."col2" = 1 AND tab1."col3" = 1;
```

in this specific place

```
tab2."col1" = tab1."col1" AND tab2."col2" = tab1."col2"
```

In the subquery I concatenate rows into string and it works great and give me the right results, something like

```
1,100;1,200;2,150....
```

I think problem is that I try to refer to objects more then one level of subquery, but I can't figure it out, how to rewrite the query.

Thanks for any help

Comment: As you are still stuck with Oracle10, your unit/management  should consider upgrading Oracle to 12c or at least 11g, where you would get the power of CTE, `LISTAGG` etc which makes those tasks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subqueries can only reference things [one level deep](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1853075500346799932). Your tab1 table is two levels away from your tab2 table.

I can't quite wrap my head around your query, but can you rewrite this so that you have a join between tab1 and tab2 instead of having a correlated query in the select clause?